# Is vibration for a new clutch job normal?

Tags: clutch, manual-transmission, vibration

I have a 2005 Toyota Camry (Manual Transmission).
My clutch died on me last week - couldn't accelerate.

I had the clutch replaced at a local mechanic. Now when I start the car off in first gear the car vibrates. I have tested by going to 1500 rpms and slowly releasing the clutch pedal. It vibrates until the clutch is fully engaged (which is almost an inch off the floor.)

Did the mechanic do a poor job or am I simply not used to the new clutch?

Edit:
I just realized that the car always vibrated in reverse. Now it vibrates both when engaging first gear or reverse.

Comment: Normally I would say that you need to get used to the clutch... but I don't think that's the case here, especially as you told me that the car still vibrates when you hold the clutch on the BITE. I think you should get your clutch checked out by another mechanic.

Comment: Isn't the bite point where it's supposed to vibrate?

Comment: Is it an involved job to look at the clutch? Don't you need to take out the transmission?

Comment: He told me it's a single unit, so he didn't need to assemble the individual parts together.

Comment: To me that sounds a little dodgy... The clutch is a pretty complex part of the car and more to the point, it should NOT vibrate ont he BITE.

Comment: From what I have read online about this kind of issue, some people are saying that it could be potentially failing flywheel.

Comment: The flywheel doesn't come with a new clutch?

Comment: Unless the flywheel is showing obvious damage, then you can just replace the clutch. Ask you mechanic to see if he/she changed the flywheel.

Comment: It's already a new clutch...

Comment: Hmmm... well in that case there is only one option left -  ask @Paulster2 what he thinks about this problem. He knows his stuff!

Comment: @Paulster2, please advise...

Comment: What size engine?

Comment: @Movemorecomments, 2.4L

Comment: @Dan, is it normal for the car to vibrate on the BITE when no gas is given?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It sounds like the flywheel is out of round, and no a flywheel doesn't typically come with the clutch.

> He told me it's a single unit, so he didn't need to assemble the
>   individual parts together.

I am not sure exactly what that means, what parts exactly did he replace? A standard clutch job includes replacing the clutch, pressure plate, throwout bearing and turning the flywheel.

I would guess that he didn't turn the flywheel, meaning machine it to make sure it's completely flat.

The other possibility is that he only replaced the clutch disk and not the pressure plate and the pressure plate is the issue, but nobody only puts a clutch disk in without the pressure plate your just asking for trouble.

Here's a breakdown of a typical clutch to illustrate the parts I am talking about

[image]

The technician should have had the flywheel turned (Machined), or at a minimum checked it for run-out as pictured below

[image]

The Maximum runout: 0.1 mm (0.004 inch) so it doesn't take much to cause a problem.

Comment: I called him up and he said that it might need a tune up. I'll mention the flywheel on my next visit. Thanks!

Comment: How much does the mentioned flywheel job usually cost?

Comment: @TheOne When it's done with the clutch job about $40 which is just the machining labor. To do just that requires complete disassembly again so that's going to be pricey about 10 hours labor. Depending on engine size, I still need that information. That's why you do it while your are already in there.

Comment: wouldn't the mechanic notice if the flywheel was off when doing the clutch job?

Comment: Is it uncommon for all those parts to be sold as one whole unit? This is a toyota camry 2005...

Comment: @TheOne he should have machined it while he was there or at a minimum checked the run out while he was there. The parts can be sold in a kit but they aren't preassembled I guess they could have be held together with the pilot tool that is used to line up the clutch to the flywheel but it cannot be preassembled to the pressure plate because the pressure plate has to be removed to unbolt the flywheel from the crank

Comment: @TheOne I have updated my answer about checking for run-out. But the bottom line is this is a comeback on the shop that did the repair and they should be responsible for the repair cost, with the exception of the cost for machining the flywheel if they didn't charge you for that already. But they should not charge you for the labor to get back to it because it should have been done in the first place.

Comment: @TheOne That is of course assuming that the vibration is coming from the clutch and is not a preexisting condition that you didn't notice before.

Comment: I made an edit to the question.

Comment: @TheOne That just makes me think the flywheel was out of round beforehand, or the pressure plate was bad, both of witch should have been fixed with the clutch job.

Comment: Will driving the car for a few days before the issue is resolved be detrimental to the car in any way?

Comment: Also will installing a new clutch to an out of round flywheel screw up the new clutch?

Comment: @TheOne No it shouldn't hurt the clutch, waiting a few days should be fine

Comment: The mechanic said he sanded the flywheel. He refuses to fix it. I guess it's time to find another mechanic or suffer through the vibrations...

Comment: Could anything else be the issue?

Comment: @TheOne Sanding it doesn't fix it, you have to machine it. It has to go on a lathe. It may be time to consider small claims court, they lean toward the consumer most of the time

Comment: @TheOne There could be other issues, best to get a second opinion from another mechanic. Actually being able to check out the car would be needed to confirm.

Comment: I am aware that sanding doesn't help. I am in the US and most cars here are autos - I just think they don't have enough experience servicing standard transmissions...

Comment: is leaving the vibrations unfixed bad for the car?

Comment: @TheOne It's going to put extra wear on the transmission, clutch and pressure plate, but it may not be enough to be significant.

Answer (score 0):

I drive a Honda 1994 Accord, and have some vibration in the pedal and some vehicle vibration right at the point the clutch begins to bite. I have never had any issues because of this. I installed the clutch, pressure plate, and flywheel myself with the guidance of an ASE certified mechanic. About 5,000+/-1k later and all is well.